# php - do I need to validate a uploaded file that will be used by file_get_contents

Tags: php, security, file-upload

I'm writting a php script where user uploads a file that will be read by the server to retrieve some data and then deleted, everything happens in the same script.

Something like:

```
// Saves the file
// Loads the file (file_get_contents)
// Retrieve data
// Delete file
```

Some notes:

- File will be stored with a random generated name during this period.
- File will have a minimum and maximum allowed size.
- Retrieved data will be properly validated before any further action

My question is: Do I need to take any further security measures during the file saving and reading?

I hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My concerns are during the upload and not while you're processing the file.

You'll want to ensure you're only allowing files of certain types.  I would avoid allowing binary or executable files.  It looks like you're having them upload text-based files so in your PHP script, use a check similar to this:

```
if ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] != "text/plain") {
   // File not the right type ... do not permit upload
}
```

Comment: I would also employ a malicious code checker that routinely checks the directory in which these files are uploaded.  I know they're removed immediately afterward, but a  malicious file could leave something behind.  You can use something like http://www.mikestowe.com/2010/10/php-malicious-code-scanner.php.

Answer (score 0):

@LuvnJesus has a good idea, except that the "type" element is set by the user agent. A better idea, if feasible, is to use a facility that actually examines the first bytes of a file. For images, and I know that is not the scenario you described, people have learned to use the GD library in clever ways to determine file type. I do not often work with files in PHP, but I would closely examine the file system functions, GD, and anything else that might be able to give you a quick "peek" at the file and make a decision base on that preview.